# Derivative of $E: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3, E(x)=Ax+c$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, affine-geometry

> Derivative of $E: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3, E(x)=Ax+c$

In general, how can I derive an affine transformation with $A\in \operatorname{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$, $x,c\in \mathbb{3}$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: Hint: use the definition of the derivative to show $DE = A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $x,h$ you have

$$E(x+h) - E(x) = Ah$$ where $h \mapsto Ah$ is linear. Therefore the derivative of $E$ at any point $x$ is the linear map $h \mapsto Ah$.

Comment: Wouldn't the second degree derivative also be $h\mapsto Ah$?

Comment: Yes this is true.

Comment: And what would happend if $x$ depended on $t$, $x(t)$ so to speak.

Comment: Would it be $Ax'(t)$ and $Ax''(t)$?

Comment: What you wrote is also true if $x$ is a real map.